# Given the exp() function, how to implement the ln() function?

Tags: algorithm, math

I came cross this question when I was in a CS job interview. I have no idea about it, let alone implement the code……

Could I get some tips?

P.S. exp() is the function y = e^x and ln() is y = ln(x)

Comment: What is the desired running time?

Comment: You will have to perform iterations of exp(y) over various values of y and check which value is closest to x.

Comment: Not required. So we can assume the running time is not strict.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Your idea can get the value of ln(x) eventually, but it's really too inefficient.

Comment: @mitcc You can improve efficiency by gradually narrowing down your search because you know that both exp and ln are monotonously increasing functions

Comment: Perhaps your best option would be to ignore the `exp` function and to compute `ln` from one of the many algorithms available which use only the basic arithmetic functions, such as a series expansion.

Comment: Binary search, maybe? Or try Newton's method on e ^ x - value = 0. Remember, d/dx (e ^ x) = e ^ x

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If so, I need to expanse ln(x) to Taylor series based on e^x.

Comment: Typically they do taylor expansion of ln(x+1) which behaves a lot nicer. ln(1+x) = x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - x^4/4 + ...

Comment: Clearly, the solution must use the exponential function, which is the inverse of the logarithm. So you have to solve `exp(y) = x` (and not use Taylor). Newton will give you the fastest convergence, but you need to check if the choice of the initial value matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find the value in log time by binary searching the answer. This is possible because log X is a monotonically increasing function.

[image]

<sub>(courtesy of [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+x+graph+from+0.2+to+10))</sub>.

For example, if the value whose logarithm we have to calculate (assume it to be X) is greater than 1, then start with an assumption of answer = X. Raise the power e^answer and check if the value is greater than or smaller than X. Now based on whether the value you get is greater than or lesser than X, you can refine your limits. The search stops when you have reached within suitable ranges of your answer.

```
double log(double X){
        double lo = 1;
        double hi = X;

        while(true){
            double mid = (lo+hi)/2;
            double val = power(e, mid);
            if(val > X){
                hi = mid;
            }
            if(val < X){
                lo = mid;
            }
            if(abs(val-X) < error){
                return mid;
            }
        }
    }
```

Similarly, if the value of X is smaller than 1, then you can reduce this case to the case we have already considered, ie. when X is greater than 1. For example if X = 0.04, then

log 0.04 = log (4/100)
         = (log 4) - (log 100)

Comment: Why do you need to separate the case for `X>1` and `X<1`?

Comment: Because for `x<1` we have `ln(x)>x` - thus, if we'll start to find with value lesser than `x` we'll never end (because `(lo+hi/2)` would also be lesser than `x`)

Comment: @justhalf what will be low set to in that case? The value of logX can be -Infinity. And we have no lower bound in that case.

Comment: I see. Then for the case `X<1`, I think you should do `ln(1/X) = -ln(X)` instead. And remember that the question is about `ln(X)`, which is the natural logarithm, not base 10.

Comment: I see that's also a nice way to reduce the problem when X<1. However I never mentioned base 10 in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

If X is positive, then the logarithm can be found using [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

X_{0} = 0

X_{n+1} = X_{n} - (exp(X_{n}) - X) / (exp(X_{n})

Very fast convergence.

Comment: Second line can be simplified to `X_{n+1} = X_{n} +  X / exp(X_{n}) - 1`.

Comment: Typo: the denominator is (exp(X_{n}) - 1). But is convergence guaranteed everywhere ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I think the denominator is correct.  `X` here is a constant, the value we're trying to find the natural log of.  (It might perhaps have been clearer if `X` were renamed `Y`, while leaving the `X_i` as they are.)

Comment: Ooops, my bad ! I was influenced by the notation (X_{n} vs X).

Comment: much faster, and easier to implement

Answer (score 5):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22706481/834521) to get X scaled in the range [0,e]. A few things we know about `ln(x)`, `ln(x)` is only defined for 0 < x, `ln(1)=0`, the results can be any number from -infinity to +infinity. `ln(x^a) = a * ln(x)` in particular `ln(x^(-1)) = - ln(x)`, `ln(X/e) = ln(X)-ln(e)` so `ln(X) = ln(X/e) + 1`.

```
double E = exp(1);
double ln(double X) {
    if(X<0) return NaN;
    // use recursion to get approx range
    if(X<1) {
       return - ln( 1 / X );
    }
    if(X>E) {
       return ln(X/E) + 1;
    }
    // X is now between 1 and e
    // Y is between 0 and 1

    double lo = 0;
    double hi = 1;

    while(true){
        double mid = (lo+hi)/2;
        double val = exp(mid);
        if(val > X){
            hi = mid;
        }
        if(val < X){
            lo = mid;
        }
        if(abs(val-X) < error){
            return mid;
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at the actual implementations of mathematical functions in the libraries. They do quite a lot of prescaling work to narrow the ranges of input, probably more aggressive than is done here.